# How to change Icon of Application Instance

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons, themes

I'm new to Linux, and currently running Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with KDE Plasma 5.12.7.

I have installed an icon theme which replaces folder icons etc. I have also changed Dolphin to use an orange folder icon instead of the default blue icon. Whenever I open an instance of Dolphin, however, the icon displayed in the panel is the default icon. How can I change which icon is displayed here?

I've tried changing the icon by right clicking the link in the panel (that's how I set the image to the orange folder in the first place.)
I tried changing the application icon in Dolphin's File Type Options, I tried rebooting to see if the icon would be propagated on a restart, though none of these approaches worked.

Please let me know if you need any further system information, and thank you for your time! :-)

In the image below, on the left you will see the Dolphin link as an orange folder at the top of the panel beneath Konsole, and the blue Dolphin instances halfway down the panel.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The Dolphin, KDE File manager, application icon is set in the main.cpp - https://cgit.kde.org/dolphin.git/tree/src/main.cpp#n60 :

```
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon::fromTheme(QStringLiteral("system-file-manager"), app.windowIcon()));
```

The Dolphin will use the icon theme icon 'system-file-manager' as the application icon:

[image]